# QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme

Tags: themes, gtk, qt

When I start any Qt app, I get this message in the terminal, and the Qt app doesn't use the same theme as my Gtk apps:

```
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
```

How do I make QGtkStyle detect my current GTK+ theme?

It seems that LXDE is using a settings daemon, and there is no gtkrc-2.0 file in my home folder.

Comment: I have the same problem running Medusa4 (a cad programme), but I'm not sure I have the .grkrc-2.0 file anywhere. I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed. Could someone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
export GTK2_RC_FILES="$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0"
```

Also make sure you defined a theme in yout **gtkrc-2.0** like this:

```
gtk-theme-name="myTheme"
```